# 'AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'file'' when using oauth2client with Google Calendar

Tags: python, calendar, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, oauth2client

I'm using the example script for google calendars python api (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample) to try and print out all the calendar events.  However I am getting an error of:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'file'
```

from the line

```
store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
```

I can find no references to such an error in the docs.  Has anyone else come across this before?

Cheers,
Jack

Comment: Can you add more of your code? The problem may lie in lines of code before that section, namely from the instantiation of the oauth2client object or the credential_path argument.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In original sample

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample

missing import entry:

```
   from oauth2client import file
```

add this line and try run your script again